# Get all pages that are published

Tags: pages

I need to get all visible (published) pages and then determine which template they use. I need to do this in standard WordPress API not via the REST API.

Is there a function that can do that?

Comment: you can get that with https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts

Comment: You can simply view them from the body classes. If you need a programmatic solution, you can print the global `$template` variable in footer. That will print the path to the current file being used in footer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `get_pages` to get all the published pages, which is similar to `get_posts`, as

```
<?php $args = array(
    'sort_order' => 'asc',
    'sort_column' => 'post_title',
    'hierarchical' => 1,
    'exclude' => '',
    'include' => '',
    'meta_key' => '',
    'meta_value' => '',
    'authors' => '',
    'child_of' => 0,
    'parent' => -1,
    'exclude_tree' => '',
    'number' => '',
    'offset' => 0,
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
); 
$pages = get_pages($args); // get all pages based on supplied args

foreach($pages as $page){ // $pages is array of object
   $page_template = get_post_meta($page->ID, '_wp_page_template', true); // Page template stored in "_wp_page_template"

   echo $page_template;
}

?>
```

Checkout these links for more detail:

get pages: <s>https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages</s>

2022.06.18 - This page has been moved to https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_pages/

get page template: <s>https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_template</s>

2022.06.18 - This page has been moved to https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_template/